# Looking for an affirmative answer

Tags: tense, past-tense

is correct if I ask after an affirmative sentence from someone:

Someone: My parents were Chinese, but I don’t speak Chinese. 
Me: “You did not learn”

or is better to say just:
Me: You never learned.

Someone: yes

Answer (score 1):

Either of these would be correct. But the first form seems to me to be slightly accusatory, as if to say, "The reason you don't speak Chinese is because you took no actions to do so, even though you undoubtedly could have learned it from your parents, had you bothered at all." The other form is more of an observation than an accusation, at least to my ear.

Comment: To me, the obvious question would be "Didn't you ever learn?". In either case, the other person would reply "No (I didn't)", not "Yes (you are right)".